# Convert from object[,] to List<Class> in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, .net-4.5

I have array `object[,]` with values from Excel (integers, doubles, dates), and I have class:

```
class Foo1
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public Bar B {get; set;}
    public List<Baz> C {get; set;}
    public double D {get; set;}
}
```

I need to convert data from array to values in class fields.

I have different `Foo` classes with integers, Lists, etc. for other arrays. 
Arrays have size [40,70] or [100, 144] (example).

Some code:

```
var data[,] = { {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, ...}, {5.5, 6.6, 7.7 ...} }
var dest = new List<Foo1>();
```

And I have mappings for `dest[0]` item:

```
row | col | destination
-----------------------
 0  |  0  | dest[0].A
 0  |  1  | dest[0].B.SomeField
 0  |  2  | dest[0].C.first_item
 0  |  3  | dest[0].C.second_item
 0  |  4  | dest[0].D
```

`dest[1]` item starts in row 1.

I want in result `List<Foo1>`

```
dest[0].A = 1.1
dest[0].B.some_field = 2.2
dest[0].C[0].some_field = 3.3
dest[0].C[1].some_field = 4.4
....
dest[1].A = 5.5
dest[1].B.some_field = 6.6
```

How to do it as fast as possible without millions of `if`, `foreach`.

Comment: you're question is not very clear, and doesn't even show an effort to solve the problem. You might want to improve it, before it'll get closed ...

Comment: I have no idea what you're after. Can you explain this in a way that doesn't require us to be domain experts .. ?

Comment: Could you please formulate the problem more clearly? Also, give some complete example and stress the point, where you stuck. Some given inputs and required outputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something hardcoded for your `Foo1`, or something generic? Also, how do you indicate the end of your list?

Comment: The question is how to do it using for example LINQ (?): it is possible? @hvd rather generic

Comment: @Tomasito Then consider `class Foo2 { public List<Bar> P1 { get; set; } public List<Bar> P2 { get; set; } }`, and your array row contains four `Bar` objects. How many of those should be put in `P1`, and how many in `P2`? If you hardcode for a specific type, you can use whatever makes sense for that type, but if you want something generic, then complicated questions such as this really need to be answered first.

Comment: @hvd it depends on array, this is the part of problem. Now mapping is written in text file that I must translate to working code.

Comment: OK, I think I know what you're trying to achieve. Question is, what have you tried already?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek In this case, I asked for some help :)

Comment: I don't think that's enough. Questions asking for code has to contain your attempts and what's wrong with them. It's not *I need a code which does that* site.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Just right direction which could I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that does what you want using expression trees. It can be easily generalized to the exact case you describe in your question:

```
    class X
    {
        public string Y { get; set; }
    }

    class Foo1
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public X B { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo1));

        Dictionary<int, Expression> map = new Dictionary<int, Expression>()
        { { 0, Expression.Property(
                   instanceParameter,
                   "A") },
          { 1, Expression.Property(
                   Expression.Property(instanceParameter, "B"),
                   "Y" ) } };
        //more properties can be defined easily

        object[,] data = new object[4, 2];
        data[0, 0] = 1;
        data[0, 1] = "asdf";
        data[1, 0] = 2;
        data[1, 1] = "yyy";
        data[2, 0] = -1;
        data[2, 1] = "xxx";
        data[3, 0] = 3;
        data[3, 1] = "good luck!";

        List<Foo1> result = new List<Foo1>();
        for (int row = 0; row < data.GetLength(0); ++row)
        {
            var foo = new Foo1() { B = new X() };

            for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); ++col)
            {
                Expression
                    .Lambda<Action<Foo1>>(
                        Expression.Assign(
                            map[col],
                            Expression.Constant(data[row, col])),
                        instanceParameter)
                    .Compile()(foo);
            }

            result.Add(foo);
        }
    }
```

I wouldn't recommend this in general - it is unreadable and hard to maintain. Any type errors will be very hard to diagnose. Yet, it's fully automated as requested.

Usually you should just use some kind of serialization. If you can't (you can't influence type of the data your receive, from some API for example), then usually each object should know by itself how to read its properties from the given structure. I.e.:

```
class Foo1
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public Bar B {get; set;}
    public List<Baz> C {get; set;}
    public double D {get; set;}

    public void Decode(object[,] data, int rowNumber)
    {
        this.A = (int)data[rowNumber, 0];
        //this.B = new Bar(); perhaps
        this.B.Decode(data, rowNumber);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Again, if you already have lots of such classes of similar structure and can't do anything about it or are forced by some other circumstances you should use the expression approach.

Comment: If not your solution, because it is not recommended, what other approach to the problem?

Comment: @Tomasito I've added a description of more common approaches.

Comment: @Tomasito Usually there is no point in wondering about that. If you can, use the most readable solution (serialization or my version with `Decode`). Only after you'll notice performance problem use a profiler to diagnose were the bottleneck exactly is. Thinking about performance before actually doing anything is *most of the time* pointless. Having said that, the expression version probably will work slower.

Comment: I try both solutions, first that with forgotten Expression Trees.